# Load required javascripts and css only

Tags: javascript, html, css, compression, minify

Is there any way to exclude unused javascript and css code and load only the required code for a particular web page?

Lets take an example, In web development, for any web page, there are so many javascripts and css files get included. though the page requires only 20% of the code. Is there some tool which finds dependencies and create a bundle for required code (say 20%) only.

Platform:
Web server: Apache, nginx
Scripting language: php

Comment: if the page only requires 20% of the linked files then why are you linking to the rest ??

Comment: 20% is just a number. There are so many common files get loaded for accomplishing common functionality to display some layers, banners etc.

Answer (score 0):

For controlling excess JS files take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) as for CSS I'm afraid you will probably need to rely on discipline.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [$import.js](http://w3core.github.io/import.js/) utility that allows dynamically control JS and CSS files as well. Less files also supports but requires additional compiling logic.